# Laravel 5.4 POST to API redirect 302 rather than returning validation error

Tags: php, laravel, api

I am trying to POST to my API, but for some reason, all POST requests return a 302. GET requests seem fine. I cannot see why I am getting a 302.

Route in `api.php`

```
Route::resource('calculator', 'Api\CalculatorController', ['only' => ['index', 'store']]);
```

Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests\CalculatorValuationRequest;

class CalculatorController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return response()->json(['test' => 1]);
    }

    public function store(CalculatorValuationRequest $request)
    {
        return response()->json(['this is a test']);
    }
}
```

Request Validator

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class CalculatorValuationRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'products' => ['required', 'array'],
            'products.*' => ['numeric', 'min:0.01', 'nullable'],
        ];
    }
}
```

Routes:

```
+--------+----------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI                  | Name                 | Action                                                   | Middleware   |
+--------+----------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | /                    | index                | Closure                                                  | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/calculator       | calculator.index     | App\Http\Controllers\Api\CalculatorController@index      | api          |
|        | POST     | api/calculator       | calculator.store     | App\Http\Controllers\Api\CalculatorController@store      | api          |
|        | POST     | api/contact          |                      | App\Http\Controllers\Api\ContactController@postContact   | api          |
```

Request & Response

```
curl -X POST \  
  http://localhost:8000/api/calculator \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: application/json' \
  -d '{"products": ["1" => "this is a test", "7" => "3"]}'
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=http://localhost:8000" />

        <title>Redirecting to http://localhost:8000</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Redirecting to <a href="http://localhost:8000">http://localhost:8000</a>.
    </body>
</html>%
```

Example response when hitting route calculator.index showing GET requests work fine:

```
curl -X GET \
   http://localhost:8000/api/calculator \
   -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
   -H 'content-type: application/json' \
   -d '{"name": "asdf"}'
{"test":1}%
```

I die and dump `dd('mytest')` inside the `CalculatorValuationRequest::rules()` method, and that works, so it appears as though when Validation fails, Laravel is trying to redirect rather than return 422 with validation response.

How do I get the validator to actually return an error rather than trying to redirect the user for API requests?

Answer (score 36):

When visiting the endpoint using Postman, set the Header

`Accept: application/json`

or Laravel would never know it's an API client and thus redirect with 302 message.
It's the mechanism for latest Laravel version since they provide api.php router beside web.php router.

Answer (score 8):

Ok, I dug a little deeper - Despite setting the content type, laravel for some reason cannot tell - despite hitting API route that it is an AJAX request via POSTMAN / CURL.

As such, in order to resolve this issue, you need to specify the accept headers or set one / all of the following headers in the request:

- `X-Requested-With`
- `Accept` - telling that we can accept json.

See `\Illuminate\Http\Concerns\InteractsWithContentTypes::expectsJson` to see how it works.

Answer (score 8):

Laravel needs the `{"X-Requested-With":"XMLHttpRequest"}` header to detect ajax requests.

Comment: thank you! I'm testing Airlock and was getting 302 for unauthenticated calls. Adding this solved my issue and now get 401 as expected.